# What is the URL for Adobe Flex 4 RSLs?

Tags: apache-flex, url, flex4, rsl

What is the URL that Flex 4 uses to download RSLs at runtime?

I want to check if I have access to this URL and that it is not blocked by the proxy that I am behind and would like to be able to put the URL into a browser to do this.

Obviously there are many URLs (one for each swz file), but does anyone know what the basic URL pattern is, or can anyone give me a sample URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it: fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.5.0.20967/… (for example)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know if Flash Player can't find signed SWZs on the provided url it tries to download them from http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/

Comment: I get a "404 not found" if I try that URL, do you?

Comment: Ok, I found it: http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.5.0.20967/rpc_4.5.0.20967.swz (for example)